# Navigation Bar + presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I have a navigation bar based application, and at one specific point in the app I have a button on the nav bar that should present a new view using a flip transition (essentially taking a user from a tableview to a map view). I'm currently using

```
 DetailLocationView *detailLocationView = [DetailLocationView alloc] init];
 detailLocationView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self.view presentModalViewController:detailLocationView animated:YES];
 [detailLocationView release];
```

This code takes the entire view the user is in (navigation bar and table view) and flips it into just the detailLocationView. However, I would like for the detailLocationView to still have a navigation bar. I'm wondering what the best way to have the detailLocationView be loaded in so that it has a flip transition and is still has a navigation bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pushViewController instead of presentModalViewController will retain the navbar, but will not as you want.

If you want to "flip" and still have the Navbar - you'd have to flip to a new view with the navbar. This is sort of illogical though, from a UI perspective - i.e. when you visually see the view flip - you're seeing it change to something completely different - so for the view to flip and then reveal the *same* navbar may be a bit confusing.